# Error in adding dependency in android

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

When I have following code gradle is build successfully.

```
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.2.1'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge:CustomGauge:1.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'



}
```

But when I added below dependency it stated giving me error.

```
 compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.9'
```

error

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Any suggestions.
Thanks

complete gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zriton.udhaar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.2.1'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge:CustomGauge:1.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'



    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.9'

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the latest version of Google's libs installed. 23.2.1 should be 23.4.0.

The solution is at the bottom, "`Install Repository`"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to install the "Android Support Repository" in the Android SDK Manager.

If you have the android tools on your path, just go to the Terminal and run:

`$ android`

You can also access it via Android Studio > Tools > Android > SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The support library that you are using is 23.2.1, but  in error it is showing 23.4.0, replace your current version to 23.4.0 and try to sync project

Comment: can you provide the complete gradle file so that i can find another solution?